# pick a random records from a datatable

Tags: c#, random, datatable

I'm trying to create an application which import an excel file and read the data from it and it returns *n* records randomly as winners according to how many winners the user want from that list. so i read the data from excel file and assign it to a `datatable` called `dt`. here is a small overview

[image]

thats the first 30 records in the excel which will be imported to `dt`. now if user key in 10(thats the total number of winners), i need to pick 10 winners "RANDOMLY" from this `dt`, but as you can see some of them are duplicated for example: in column D, the entry named "H" has 6 rows. now if the application chose 1 of them, the others "H" have to be removed but that is after it has been chosen. removing the duplicates before choosing any of them, will lower the chance for them to win better prizes.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: Your question is missing a lot of focus.  First you point to another article and say that you don't know how to follow it, then you start talking about duplicate records, which wouldn't affect you picking random results, but might cause multiple similar random results.  Ultimately, it's really unclear where to even start with an answer here.

Comment: Why not generate the IDs in program and the IDs will be the winner, after that, use SQL to select data of the winner's ID?

Comment: @User2012384 im not reading the data from sql, and i tried the ID as well but it didnt work. hold on a min ...im trying to edit the question so it will be easier to understand

Comment: @Ali Oh sorry, then you can also gen the id in program then use DataTable.Select method to select the IDs generated... e.g. use Math.Random to generate ids

Comment: Do you really need to keep duplicated records on your data table to begin with? why not remove the duplicates first and then simply choose a random X rows?

Comment: @ZoharPeled yes....i need to keep them since the chance of winning for them is higher in that way.

Comment: @Claies i edited the post, im not sure if this edit is better or not but well...i tried to explain it step by step this time

Comment: You still haven't shown any code illustrating what you have attempted; now you're just showing a table and trying to describe what you want your code to do, rather than what you are having trouble doing.

Comment: @Claies well...you understood my problem this time :D i havent shown any codes because i dont know how to do it! i mean i dont know how to pick random records from datatable in a way that 1-its randomly picked, 2-it is picked in a manner that any other record which has the same "IC NUMBER" will not be picked again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try something like,

```
dt2 = dt.Clone();
dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x["IC_NUMBER"].ToString()).Distinct().ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("IC_NUMBER = '" + x + "'");
    dt2.ImportRow(dr[0]);
    dr.ToList().ForEach(y => dt.Rows.Remove(y));
    dt.AcceptChanges();
});
```

EDIT:

```
int totalWinners = 10;
Random rnd = new Random();
dt2 = dt.Clone();
for (int i = 1; i <= totalWinners; i++)
{
    //Pick random datarow
    DataRow selectedWinner = dt.Rows[rnd.Next(0, dt.Rows.Count - 1)];
    //Insert it in the second table
    dt2.ImportRow(selectedWinner);
    //Retrieve other datarows that have same 'IC NUMBER'
    var rows = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["IC NUMBER"].ToString() ==
                                            selectedWinner["IC NUMBER"].ToString());
    //Delete all the rows with the selected IC NUMBER in the first table
    rows.ToList().ForEach(y => dt.Rows.Remove(y));
    dt.AcceptChanges();
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: i get a Syntax error: Missing operand after 'NUMBER' operator.

Comment: If `IC NUMBER` is a string field then modify the datarow filter to this `DataRow[] dr = dt.Select("IC NUMBER = '" + x + "'");` or try to change the column name `IC NUMBER` to something else like `IC_NUMBER` because `NUMBER` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: still the same error. i dont think its string, i think the cells of the columns in a datatable are object

Comment: @Ali Could you try the edited one as per your edited requirement?

Comment: Column 'IC_NUMBER' does not belong to table at this line `x["IC_NUMBER"] == selectedWinner["IC_NUMBER"]`

Comment: Column 'IC_NUMBER' does not belong to table . at `x["IC_NUMBER"] == selectedWinner["IC_NUMBER"]`

Comment: Please refer the edited answer. I have already changed that line to `x["IC NUMBER"].ToString() == selectedWinner["IC NUMBER"].ToString()`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80862/discussion-between-ali-and-vanest).